# C++ unable to declare a string in a derived class

Tags: c++, class

I hope this doesn't seem rushed, because it is. So I have this namespace:

```
namespace Roles_Lib {
class Roles {
public:
    virtual void attack();
    virtual void defend();
    virtual void heal();
    int attackStat;
    int health;
    int level;
};

class Player : public Roles {
public:
    Player();
    void attack();
    void defend();
    void heal();
    string playerName;
};

class Enemy : public Roles {
public:
    Enemy();
    void attack();
    void defend();
    void heal();
    void spawn();
    int createName();
    string enemyName;
};
}
```

However, when I try and compile it (along with other code) I get C3646 and C4430 errors on the lines where I declare strings. Do I have to include  or ? Error messages:

```
'playerName': unknown override specifier
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

My IDE is visual studio.
-Sorry for the rushed post.

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`? And `using namespace std;`?

Comment: Don't `using namespace std;` in a header. Just specify the fully qualified type, `std::string`.

Comment: _I hope this doesn't seem rushed, because it is_

Answer (score 1):

You should use this: `std::string playerName;`

Comment: And make sure you have `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 0):

First don't forget to add the string in header file
if it still doesn't work, Copy the code and remove the code then again paste it.
It should be solved, it happens sometime that our IDE forget that we have included string above.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Issue is with use of namespace std.